# PHPUnit - all test suite data providers are executed before first test suite

Tags: php, phpunit

I have defined test suites in my phpunit.xml..
I have them defined in the order they should be ran..

My problem is that PHPunit seems to call all the dataProviders defined across all test suites beforehand.  (effectively negates the order I defined)

Is there any way I can change this behavior?  So that it calls the dataproviders on a per-test-suite basis?

Comment: I don't know about the dataProviders, but as far as I know the PHPUnit documentation states that tests are not guaranteed to run in a specific order. You can organise them into logical groups in multiple ways, but not set the specific order in which they're run.

Comment: @MatthewSetter  TestSuites are ran in the order they are defined.. also from the documentation for TestSuites:  "The order in which tests are executed can be made explicit:"

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for the further feedback.